# How socket.io can be used like axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, socket.io, axios

I've an application, which is built in axios, just PUT, POST, DELETE, GET in mind. which looks like this

```
getAPI = axios.create(.....)
....
getAPI.post('signup/', {email, password})
          .then(res => {
          /// return some res
          })
          .catch(err => {
          /// some error is show if not succeed

          })
  }
```

and also goes or "post/", "logout/", "signup/" with different methods.
Later i found that, In order to make post actions realtime in client side , we need to use websocket.  So i used socket.io .
I've already setup server and client.

In server socket connection like this

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('User is connected on socket');
    socket.on('disconnect', () => console.log('disconnected'));
})
```

and in client connection i've searc tutorials and  used contextAPI, and passed to allcomponents.
in my specific component, where i've user post and user post is shown i've put code like this

```
  const {socket} = useContext(AuthContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("client connected")
  })
    return ()=> socket.disconnect()
  })
```

Now how can i use those of axios request with catch errors but with socket.io. It seems very hard to me using socket.io integrating with axios . Although i need not to use socket on authentication. But i need to use it on "/post" request.

Posting from client to server was easy by that axios.POST.then().catch(), axios.GET .....
but i'm confused to integrate that axios things in socket in client .

Also in backend side , i've routes like these

```
router.get('/logout', logout)
router.post('/post/create', post)
```

with each handler like these

```
exports.postCreate = (req, res) => {
  let post =   new Post(req.body)
  post.save((err, post) => {
    if(err){
      return res.status(400).json({error: "Error"})
    }
  return res.json(post)
  })
}
```

but if i want to use socket.io,  what should i do? I'm very confused by socket.io docs, not showing for handeling things.

If you have idea about these things,
please answer me Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io keeps its connections alive. In order to handle errors. You will need to listen to events. For example:
[Handling connection errors](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#event-connect_error):

```
socket.on("connect_error", (error) => {
  // ...
});
```

[Handling disconnect errors](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#event-disconnect):

```
socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
  if (reason === "io server disconnect") {
    // the disconnection was initiated by the server, you need to reconnect manually
    socket.connect();
  }
  // else the socket will automatically try to reconnect
});
```

If you'd like to ensure that your server side handled your request and need confirmation you can use the optional 'ack' feature like [this](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#socketemiteventname-args):

```
// client side
socket.emit("ferret", "tobi", (data) => {
  console.log(data); // data will be "woot"
});

// server side:
  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("ferret", (name, fn) => {
      fn("woot");
    });
  });
```